# Иностранный язык

Tags: орфография, сокращения

О факультете иностранного языка или школьном предмете часто говорят сокращенно. Но как правильно записать: "ин.яз." или "инъяз"? Вроде как это уже стало общеупотребительным словом, но слитно как-то не поднимается рука писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственная фиксация - **иняз** у Лопатина.  В таком же написании достаточно часто встречается и в текстах (нацкорпус - более 20 вхождений только в основной форме), включая написние с заглавной - Иняз.

По современным действующим правилам употребление Ъ в подобных случаях невозможно, чем бы эти "ин" и "яз" здесь не являлись (а чем, кстати?), Ъ используется только на стыке корня и приставки в соответвующих случаях и в единичных случаях - в иноязычных словах типа фельдъегерь и адъютант.

Орфографическая Комиссия (тот же Лопатин) предлагала расширить применение Ъ как раз на случаи типа "инъяз". Статус этих предложений не совсем понятен, приняты они не были, но определенная часть словарей и авторов продолжают им следовать. Хотя сам Лопатин в своем "Орфографическом словаре" дает, как уже сказал, "иняз".

Comment: Иняз - сложное слово. Ин и яз - корни.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться морфологией и этимологией подобных "корней"?
Нув в "колхозе" хоть "хоз" на корень похоже. А нацбол? Эсэр? Худрук?Тоже "сложные" слова?  
На самом деле у такой трактовки есть далекоидущие (или - растущие) корни. "Беларусь" вон пришлось объявить нечленимым заимствованием, только чтобы не отвечать на вопрос о соединитеной гласной (здесь именно -  букве). Со "сложным" инязом будет тоже самое.  
ЗЫ Думать по вашему приказанию — какая наглость, увольте! ©

Comment: Вы что на всех нападаете? Ув.  модераторы!  Уж отреагируйте как-нибудь на вечную грубость  умного хама. .

Comment: Лорана, говорите по теме - а кто на кого нападает, без вас разберутся.

Comment: мы в школе в слове вуз выделяли три корня. Кажется, и в учебнике так было

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть на тот учебник...  
Ну да не в этом дело. Чем объяснялся такой подход - вот где собака-то зарыта. Логики в нем - никакой. Плодить не имеющие морфолонического родства корни по превой прихоти - не есть гут. А в "вузовский" - тоже три корня? 

Кстати, для сиглала модератору есть кнопка "тревога". А обзываться в теме - нехорошо. ))).

Comment: я не обзывалась. Я констатировала факт.

Comment: Вы знаете, есть хорошая мудрость. 
Не спорь с дураком, между вами могут не увидеть разницы.

Answer (score 3):

Сокращение ИН. здесь - это слово ИНОЙ (иностранный).  Оно даже в сокращённом виде не является приставкой. А Ъ пишется только после приставок. Так что пишите пока "ин. яз".

Comment: Я бы тоже писал ин.яз (не слитно, а через точку).

Answer (score 2):

Словари слитное написание не фиксируют. Но если бы это слово было бы написано слитно, то без твердого  знака. Во-первых,  Ъ пишется после приставок, во-вторых, перед  Е,Ё,Ю,Я. Так же, как и детясли (детские ясли), это слово писалось бы "иняз"

Comment: > Словари слитное написание не
> фиксируют.

Фиксируют [link text][1]


  [1]: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E8%ED%FF%E7
Со всем остальным согласна )

Comment: Злрасте, Владимир Владимирович!

Comment: Ну и к чему это?

Comment: Ничего, просто я в теме.)

Comment: А.. тайные знания ) Мне, наверно, следует испугаться. Не дождетесь (с)
Алаверды. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E0%EB%E0%E2%E5%F0%E4%FB&all=x

Comment: "Не дождетесь." © 
Аллаверды. Думайте ещё.

Comment: Думать по вашему приказанию — какая наглость, увольте!

Comment: [Не дождетесь©][1]  
@Marina-ja, а без приказа - никак?  

[1]: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EF%EE&all=x